# What is the syntax of mongodump and mongorestore?

Tags: mongodb

I have a problem in my exercise:

1. Export the db atelier. For that, use the command `./mongodump -d atelier` My answwer : `$ mongodump -d atelier`
2. Import the contenu of the db atelier in the db atelier2. For that, use the command `./mongorestore` (use --help for see options). My answer : `$ mongorestore dump/atelier -d atelier2`

It doesn't work. The contenu of atelier is never copied in the db atelier2, the db atelier2 give no results so it must contains the collections of the data base atelier. Why it doesn't work ?

Please help me

Thanks

Comment: Can you give us return messages of mongorestore command ? what commands do you do to check content of your DB atelier2 ?

Answer (score 1):

The dump path has to be the final argument of mongorestore.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/

```
mongorestore -v --db atelier2 dump/atelier
```

should do the trick. If not the verbose flag -v should give hints to the deeper cause.